# Combining two arrays using nested foreach loops

Tags: php, array

I have the following arrays:

```
Array  (db_values)
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [system_name] => object_car_brand
        [value] => Alfa Romeo
        [id] => 136
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [system_name] => object_car_model
        [value] => Spider
        [id] => 137
    )

)
Array (db_attributes)
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 105
        [system_name] => object_car_brand
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 106
        [system_name] => object_car_model
    )

)
```

I combine these two using the following code:

```
       foreach($db_attributes as $db_attribute){
            foreach($db_values as $db_value){
                if($db_value["system_name"] === $db_attribute["system_name"]){
                    $update[$db_attribute["id"]] = $db_value["value"];
                }

            }

        }
```

I do not think that this is the most resource friendly way of doing it, is there a better way?

Comment: You should check the `RecursiveArrayIterator` class. (http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php). I never used it, so, I can't help much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made the assumption that there is a 1:1 relationships between the `$attributes` and `$values` array elements. With that I mean the array key in the `$attributes` array corresponds with an entry in `$values` array.

If that is the case it can be reduced to one `foreach` loop by using the key from the attributes array:

```
$combined = []; // Make sure the $combined array exists.

foreach($attributes as $key => $attribute) {

    // First check if the array key exists and that the 'system_name' is the same
    if(array_key_exists($key, $values) && $attribute['system_name'] == $values[$key]['system_name']) {

        $combined[$attribute['id']] = $values[$key]['value'];

    }

}
```

This should produce the following array with the data you have provided:

```
Array(combined)
(
    [106] => 'Alfa Romeo' 
)
```

If my assumption is incorrect, then just ignore my answer.

Comment: Your assumption is correct, the outcome of combined array is indeed what I'm looking for! Thank you, this looks alot resourcefriendlier :)

Answer (score 1):

If the `$db_attributes` array is very large, it would save quite a few cycles to normalize that array first.

```
// normalized attributes
$attributes = array();

// loop all attr results
foreach( $db_attributes as $db_attribute ) {
    // use system name as key
    $attributes[ $db_attribute['system_name'] ] = $db_attribute['id'];
}

// final results
$update = array();

// loop all value results
foreach( $db_values as $db_value ) {
    // check if value's system name exists in normalized attributes
    if ( isset( $attributes[ $db_value['system_name'] ] ) ){
        // yes, grab the id
        $attr_id = $attributes[ $db_value['system_name'] ]; 
        // add to update array using attr id as key
        $update[ $attr_id ] = $db_value['value'];
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct and indeed alot better than what I have in my opening post. The reason I'm not using it is because the attributes array will never get larger than it is right now. Thank you for your hints!

Comment: The top level keys of your arrays might be matching up by coincidence. Usually the top level keys from database results are ambiguous, so be careful. The author of the accepted answer also hinted at this. Thanks for the kind words :)